# Performance in Websockets blob decoding causing memory problems

Tags: javascript, memory, websocket, crash, garbage-collection

I have a performance problem in Javascript causing a crash lately at work. With the objective modernising our applications, we are looking into running our applications as webservers, onto which our client would connect via a browser (chrome, firefox, ...), and having all our interfaces running as HTML+JS webpages.

To give you an overview of our performance needs, our application run image processing from camera sources, running in some cases at more than 20 fps, but in the most case around 2-3fps max.

Basically, we have a Webserver written in C++, which HTTP requests, and provides the user with the HTML pages of the interface and the corresponding JS scripts of the application.
In order to simplify the communication between the two applications, I then open a web socket between the webpage and the c++ server to send formatted messages back and forth. These messages can be pretty big, up to several Mos.

It all works pretty well as long as the FPS stays relatively low. When the fps increases the following two things happen.

1. Either the c++ webserver memory footprint increases pretty fast and crashes when no more memory is available. After investigation, this happens when the network usage full, and the websocket cache fills up. I think this is due to the websocket TCP-IP way of doing stuff, as the socket must wait for the message to be sent and received to send the next one.
2. Or the browser crashes after a while, showing the Aw snap screen (see figure below). It seems in that case that the same thing more or less happen but it seems this time due to the garbage collection strategy. The other figure below shows the printscreen of the memory usage when the application is running, clearly showing saw pattern. It seems to indicate that garbage collection is doing its work at intervals that are further and further away.

[image: Aw Snap screen]

[image: Saw memory pattern]

I have trapped the problem down to very big messages (>100Ko) being sent at fast rate per second. And the bigger the message, the faster it happens. In order to use the message I receive, I start a web worker, pass the blob i received to the web worker, the webworker uses a FileReaderSync to convert the message as an ArrayBuffer, and passes it back to the main thread. I expect this to have quite a lot of copies under the hood, but I am not so well versed in JS yet so to be sure of this statement. Also, I initialy did the same thing without the webworker (FileReader), but the framerate and CPU usage were really bad...

Here is the code I call to decode the messages:

```
function OnDataMessage(msg)
{
    var webworkerDataMessage = new Worker('/js/EDXLib/MessageDecoderEvent.js'); // please no comments about this, it's actually a bit nicer on the CPU than reusing the same worker :-)
    webworkerDataMessage.onmessage = MessageFileReaderOnLoadComManagerCBack;
    webworkerDataMessage.onerror=ErrorHandler;
    webworkerDataMessage.postMessage(msg.data);
}

function MessageFileReaderOnLoadComManagerCBack(e)
{
    comManager.OnDataMessageReceived(e.data);
}
```

and the webworker code:

```
function DecodeMessage(msg)
{
    var retMsg = new FileReaderSync().readAsArrayBuffer(msg);
    postMessage(retMsg);
}

function receiveDecodingRequest(e)
{
    DecodeMessage(e.data);
}

addEventListener("message", receiveDecodingRequest, true);
```

My question are the following:

1. Is there a way to make the GC not have to collect so much memory, by for instance telling some of the parts I use to reuse buffers instead of recreating them, or keeping the GC work intervals fixed ? This is something I know how to do in C++, but in JS ?
2. Is there another method I should use for my big payloads? Keep in mind that the transmission should be as fast as possible.
3. Is there another method for reading blob data as arraybuffers that would faster than what I did?

I thank you in advance for you help/comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the memory problem was due to the new WebWorker line and the new FileReaderSync line in the WebWorker.

Removing these greatly improved the performances!

Also, it turns out that this decoding operation is not necessary if I want to use the websocket as array buffer. I just need to set the binaryType attribute of websockets to "arraybuffer"...

So all in all, a very simple solution to a pain in the *** problem :-)